# grub-pc is half-configured on Debian jessie

Tags: debian, grub2, locale

By installing linux new kernel gave to me some problems with unattended-upgrade in the last month

```
# cat /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
Log started: 2018-05-02  00:33:09
Lettura dei changelog...
/usr/bin/locale: 1: /usr/bin/locale: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/locale: 2: /usr/bin/locale: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
Preconfigurazione dei pacchetti in corso
Selezionato il pacchetto linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 non precedentemente  
selezionato.
(Lettura del database... 207164 file e directory attualmente installati.)
Preparativi per estrarre .../linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64_3.16.56- 
1_amd64.deb...
/usr/bin/locale: 1: /usr/bin/locale: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/locale: 2: /usr/bin/locale: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
Estrazione di linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 (3.16.56-1)...
Preparativi per estrarre .../linux-image- 
amd64_3.16+63+deb8u2_amd64.deb...
Estrazione di linux-image-amd64 (3.16+63+deb8u2) su (3.16+63+deb8u1)...
Preparativi per estrarre .../linux-libc-dev_3.16.56-1_amd64.deb...
Estrazione di linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.16.56-1) su (3.16.51-3+deb8u1)...
Configurazione di linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 (3.16.56-1)...
/usr/bin/locale: 1: /usr/bin/locale: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/locale: 2: /usr/bin/locale: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/bin/gettext: 1: /usr/bin/gettext: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/gettext: 2: /usr/bin/gettext: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 
2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux- 
image-3.16.0-6-amd64.postinst line 634.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 (-- 
configure):
il sottoprocesso installato script di post-installation ha restituito lo 
stato di errore 1
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di linux- 
image-amd64:
linux-image-amd64 dipende da linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64; comunque:
Il pacchetto linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
Configurazione di linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.16.56-1)...
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64
linux-image-amd64
Error in function: 
Log ended: 2018-05-02  00:36:46

Log started: 2018-05-05  13:26:51
Lettura dei changelog...
/usr/bin/locale: 1: /usr/bin/locale: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/locale: 2: /usr/bin/locale: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
(Lettura del database... 210939 file e directory attualmente installati.)
Preparativi per estrarre .../libmad0_0.15.1b-8+deb8u1_amd64.deb...
Estrazione di libmad0:amd64 (0.15.1b-8+deb8u1) su (0.15.1b-8)...
Configurazione di linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 (3.16.56-1)...
/usr/bin/locale: 1: /usr/bin/locale: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/locale: 2: /usr/bin/locale: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-amd64
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-amd64
(/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-amd64) -- doing nothing at 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64.postinst line 263.
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64
) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64
(/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64) -- doing nothing at 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64.postinst line 263.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/bin/gettext: 1: /usr/bin/gettext: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/gettext: 2: /usr/bin/gettext: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
 run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 
2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux- 
image-3.16.0-6-amd64.postinst line 634.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 (-- 
configure):
il sottoprocesso installato script di post-installation ha restituito lo 
stato di errore 1
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di linux- 
image-amd64:
linux-image-amd64 dipende da linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64; comunque:
Il pacchetto linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
Configurazione di libmad0:amd64 (0.15.1b-8+deb8u1)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10)...
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64
linux-image-amd64
Error in function: 
Log ended: 2018-05-05  13:28:47

Log started: 2018-05-06  10:01:20
Lettura dei changelog...
/usr/bin/locale: 1: /usr/bin/locale: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/locale: 2: /usr/bin/locale: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
Preconfigurazione dei pacchetti in corso
(Lettura del database... 210939 file e directory attualmente installati.)
Preparativi per estrarre .../tzdata_2018e-0+deb8u1_all.deb...
Estrazione di tzdata (2018e-0+deb8u1) su (2018d-0+deb8u1)...
Configurazione di tzdata (2018e-0+deb8u1)...
/usr/bin/locale: 1: /usr/bin/locale: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/locale: 2: /usr/bin/locale: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Rome'
Local time is now:      Sun May  6 10:01:48 CEST 2018.
Universal Time is now:  Sun May  6 08:01:48 UTC 2018.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

Configurazione di linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 (3.16.56-1)...
/usr/bin/locale: 1: /usr/bin/locale: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/locale: 2: /usr/bin/locale: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-amd64
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-amd64
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-amd64) -- doing nothing at 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64.postinst line 263.
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64
) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64
(/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64) -- doing nothing at 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64.postinst line 263.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/bin/gettext: 1: /usr/bin/gettext: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/gettext: 2: /usr/bin/gettext: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 
2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux- 
image-3.16.0-6-amd64.postinst line 634.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 (-- 
configure):
il sottoprocesso installato script di post-installation ha restituito lo 
stato di errore 1
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di linux- 
image-amd64:
linux-image-amd64 dipende da linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64; comunque:
Il pacchetto linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64 non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64
linux-image-amd64
Error in function: 
Log ended: 2018-05-06  10:04:18
```

After that  [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=125247) fixed my issue I tried to purge and reinstall grub2 and after follow the steps I obtained this

```
# dpkg --configure -a 
Configurazione di grub-pc (2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1)...
/usr/bin/locale: 1: /usr/bin/locale: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/locale: 2: /usr/bin/locale: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
/usr/bin/locale: 1: /usr/bin/locale: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/locale: 2: /usr/bin/locale: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installazione completata, nessun errore segnalato.
/usr/bin/gettext: 1: /usr/bin/gettext: %!PS-Adobe-3.0: not found
/usr/bin/gettext: 2: /usr/bin/gettext: Syntax error: word unexpected 
(expecting ")")
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto grub-pc (--configure):
il sottoprocesso installato script di post-installation ha restituito lo 
stato di errore 2
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
```

My concern is that if the conflict is not grub and then the reinstall of grub does not work, then there will be no way to boot. 
I didn't solve by chroot also, only repair grub doesn't work.
My dpkg status file tells me on grub-pc

```
Package: grub-pc
Status: install ok half-configured
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 514
Maintainer: GRUB Maintainers <pkg-grub-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: grub2
Version: 2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1
Replaces: grub, grub-common (<= 1.97~beta2-1), grub-coreboot, grub-efi-$
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-22+d$
Conflicts: grub (<< 0.97-54), grub-coreboot, grub-efi-amd64, grub-efi-i$
Conffiles:
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 269828d3b8e5bfb266c58fb0a00abcd5
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 269828d3b8e5bfb266c58fb0a00abcd5
...
```

Other informations:

```
# uname -r
3.16.0-6-amd64
# apt-cache policy grub-pc
grub-pc:
Installato: 2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1
Candidato:  2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1
Tabella versione:
*** 2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1 0
500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
# ls -al /vmlinuz*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 mag  2 00:35 /vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-6- 
amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 gen 26 13:30 /vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz- 
3.16.0-5-amd64
# ls -a /initrd.img*
/initrd.img  /initrd.img.old
# ls -al /boot
totale 62164
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 mag 11 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root     4096 mag 11 14:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   157756 dic 14 22:27 config-3.16.0-4-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   157786 gen  9 12:42 config-3.16.0-5-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   157842 mag  8 19:36 config-3.16.0-6-amd64
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 mag 12 10:47 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 15164265 mag  7 11:27 initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 15164783 gen 26 13:31 initrd.img-3.16.0-5-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 15310597 mag 11 11:35 initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2684316 dic 14 22:27 System.map-3.16.0-4-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2683305 gen  9 12:42 System.map-3.16.0-5-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2683087 mag  8 19:36 System.map-3.16.0-6-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3137712 dic 14 22:25 vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3139776 gen  9 12:40 vmlinuz-3.16.0-5-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3170464 mag  8 19:34 vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-amd64
# df -h
File system     Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
/dev/sda1        46G   21G     24G  47% /
udev             10M     0     10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           401M  6,0M    395M   2% /run
tmpfs          1001M   28M    973M   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K    5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          1001M     0   1001M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       180G   34G    137G  20% /home
tmpfs           201M   12K    201M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       3,8G  3,8G       0 100% /media/stefano/Debian 8.0.0 amd64 
1
# df -i
File system       Inode IUsati  ILiberi IUso% Montato su
/dev/sda1       3055616 448579  2607037   15% /
udev             253925    424   253501    1% /dev
tmpfs            256068    604   255464    1% /run
tmpfs            256068    129   255939    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            256068      4   256064    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            256068     13   256055    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2      11968512 320153 11648359    3% /home
tmpfs            256068     18   256050    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1             0      0        0     - /media/stefano/Debian 8.0.0 
amd64 1
```

**Edit 1**

My locale-file

```
# locale
/usr/bin/locale: riga 1: fg: nessun controllo dei job
/usr/bin/locale: riga 2: errore di sintassi vicino al token non atteso 
"ImageMagick"
/usr/bin/locale: riga 2: `%%Creator: (ImageMagick)'
# cat /etc/default/locale 
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="it_IT.UTF-8"
# gettext -d coreutils -s "write error"/usr/bin/gettext: riga 1: fg: 
nessun controllo dei job
/usr/bin/gettext: riga 2: errore di sintassi vicino al token non atteso 
"ImageMagick"
/usr/bin/gettext: riga 2: `%%Creator: (ImageMagick)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `/usr/bin/locale` and `/usr/bin/gettext` commands are encountering something that looks like a PostScript document header, and that is causing some errors. Those errors may or may not be the root cause of your problems, but they're definitely interfering with other system functionality.

Do you have something strange in `/etc/default/locale`, perhaps? It should contain only `sh`-style variable definitions and/or comments.

What happens if you run `locale`? It should display your current locale settings, and no error messages.

Or what if you run `gettext -d coreutils -s "write error"`? It should output a translated version of the "write error" message, according to your current locale settings.

Or perhaps a PostScript file has found its way into your message catalog directory? Then this command might find it:

```
find /usr/share/locale -type f -exec file {} \+ |grep -E -v 'GNU (gettext )?message catalog'
```

The command should identify any files under /usr/share/locale which are not message catalog files. If your `file` command output is also translated, you may have to prefix this command with `LC_ALL=C` to have tme messages in standard US English so the search string will correctly exclude the message catalog files from the output.

---

It turned out that your `/usr/bin/locale` and apparently also `/usr/bin/gettext` seem to have been replaced with PostScript files created by ImageMagick. This sounds like possible filesystem corruption, or perhaps an "oops" with ImageMagick commands while running as root.

To repair your `/usr/bin/locale` and `/usr/bin/gettext`, run this command:

```
apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin gettext-base
```

This will reinstall all files of the `libc-bin` and `gettext-base` package without removing any of the packages that depend on them first. This should fix at least some of your original error messages. Then you can try running `dpkg --configure -a` again to see if this was the true root cause of your entire problem, or if there is still more that needs fixing.

The possibility of filesystem corruption makes me think you should check `dmesg | less` output: is there anything that looks like a disk error?

Does `smartctl -a /dev/<your system disk device>` say the disk passes its internal SMART health checks? The command outputs a lot of information, but the important part should look like this:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

If it does not say "PASSED", your disk is failing and should be replaced.

Even if `smartctl` thinks the disk is OK, a full backup and then a full filesystem check might be a good idea. If you need help with the filesystem check, please open a new question for it.

Comment: find command gave me nothing

Comment: Good, it means there were no unexplainable PostScript files in there then. Your `locale` command (or some file it reads) seems to be corrupted somehow. If you have the `debsums` package installed, you could verify it with `debsums libc-bin`. If not, try `file /usr/bin/locale`: what does it say?

Comment: for telcoM  #file /usr/bin/locale
/usr/bin/locale: PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, Level 1 and debsums libc-bin tell me /usr/bin/locale FAILED

Comment: Yes, looks like your `locale` command has been replaced with a PostScript file. That's not right. See my updated answer for suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: reinstalling libc-bin and gettext-base fixed the problem! smartctl test passed so my disk appears Ok. Checking filesystem with further test will be done